# recognize html in php files in Webstorm

Tags: php, html, webstorm

I using WebStorm 7, but currently have a project when some php code exist and all html markup wraped into `*.php` files.

Is there is a way to configure Webstorm recognize html inside php files without throwing a billion errors?

Comment: I don't get the problem, you should be able to mix php and html in .php files

Comment: Assign `*.php` pattern to "HTML Files" in `Settings | File Types` -- this will make IDE treat php files as html ones. Yes, WebStorm will still complain on PHP tags (as it knows nothing about them). Alternatively see if "TextMate bundles support" plugin available for WebStorm and if it can do any better job.